# The supplied model is not a clustering estimator in YellowBrick

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, expectation-maximization, yellowbrick

I am trying to visualize an elbow plot for my data using YellowBrick's KElbowVisualizer and SKLearn's Expectation Maximization algorithm class: GaussianMixture.

When I run this, I get the error in the title. (I have also tried ClassificationReport, but that fails as well)

```
model = GaussianMixture()

data = get_data(data_name, preprocessor_name, train_split=0.75)
X, y, x_test, y_test = data

visualizer = KElbowVisualizer(model, k=(4,12))
visualizer.fit(X)        # Fit the data to the visualizer
visualizer.show()        # Finalize and render the figure
```

I cannot find anything in YellowBrick to help me estimate the number of components for expectation maximization.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yellowbrick [uses the sklearn estimator type checks](https://github.com/DistrictDataLabs/yellowbrick/blob/develop/yellowbrick/utils/types.py#L111) to determine if a model is well suited to the visualization. You can use the [`force_model` param](https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/classifier/prcurve.html#module-yellowbrick.classifier.prcurve) to bypasses the type checking (though it seems that the `KElbow` documentation needs to be updated with this).

However, even though `force_model=True` gets you through the `YellowbrickTypeError` it still does not mean that `GaussianMixture` works with `KElbow`. This is because the elbow visualizer is set up to work with the centroidal clustering API and requires both a `n_clusters` hyperparam and a `labels_` learned param. Expectation maximization models do not support this API.

However, it is possible to create a wrapper around the Gaussian mixture model that will allow it to work with the elbow visualizer (and a similar method could be used with the classification report as well).

```
from sklearn.base import ClusterMixin
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
from yellowbrick.cluster import KElbow
from yellowbrick.datasets import load_nfl

class GMClusters(GaussianMixture, ClusterMixin):

    def __init__(self, n_clusters=1, **kwargs):
        kwargs["n_components"] = n_clusters
        super(GMClusters, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def fit(self, X):
        super(GMClusters, self).fit(X)
        self.labels_ = self.predict(X)
        return self 


X, _ = load_nfl()
oz = KElbow(GMClusters(), k=(4,12), force_model=True)
oz.fit(X)
oz.show()
```

This does produce a KElbow plot (though not a great one for this particular dataset):

[image: KElbow with distortion score]

Another answer mentioned Calinksi Harabasz scores, which you can use in the `KElbow` visualizer as follows:

```
oz = KElbow(GMClusters(), k=(4,12), metric='calinski_harabasz', force_model=True)
oz.fit(X)
oz.show()
```

Creating the wrapper isn't ideal, but for model types that don't fit the standard classifier or clusterer sklearn APIs, they are often necessary and it's a good strategy to have in your back pocket for a number of ML tasks.

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you! It should really be in the YB docs

Comment: This is great! I don't know if the API changed since this was written, but I got good results by skipping the `__init__()` override, and adding kwargs key overrides to `set_params()` and `get_params()`...with that, I was able to use all of the scoring metrics, including distortion. Added as a separate answer, but this could just be edited I guess...

Answer (score 3):

Buiding on @bbengfort's great answer, I used:

```
class GaussianMixtureCluster(GaussianMixture, ClusterMixin):
    """Subclass of GaussianMixture to make it a ClusterMixin."""

    def fit(self, X):
        super().fit(X)
        self.labels_ = self.predict(X)
        return self

    def get_params(self, **kwargs):
        output = super().get_params(**kwargs)
        output["n_clusters"] = output.get("n_components", None)
        return output

    def set_params(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs["n_components"] = kwargs.pop("n_clusters", None)
        return super().set_params(**kwargs)
```

This lets you use any scoring metric, and works with the latest version of YellowBrick.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the sklearn `calinski_harabasz_score`- see the relevant docs [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.calinski_harabasz_score.html).

```
scores = pd.DataFrame()
components = 100
for n in range(2,components):
    model = GaussianMixture(n_components=n)
    y = model.fit_predict(X)
    scores.loc[n,'score'] = calinski_harabasz_score(X,y)
plt.plot(scores.reset_index()['index'],scores['score'])
```

Something like this should give similar functionality.